# imprimir un array string en c

Tags: array, c

hola amigos me pueden ayudar con mi codigo, tengo que ingresar n numero de materias y capturar sus datos pero a la hora de imprimir no me los muestra, me podrian ayudar por favor, este es mi codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i, n, j;
    char nombre[9][9],grupo[9][9],salon[9][9],profesor[9][9],horario[9][9];
    printf("Cuantas materias quieres capturar\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<1; j++){
        printf("Nombre de la materia no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&nombre[i][j]);
        printf("Grupo no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&grupo[i][j]);
        printf("Salon no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&salon[i][j]);
        printf("Profesor no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&profesor[i][j]);
        printf("Horario no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&horario[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("**********REPORTE DE MATERIAS CURSADAS  ACTUALMENTE************\n");
    printf("NOMBRE\tGRUPO\tSALON\tPROFESOR\tHORARIO\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("%c",nombre[i][j]);
            printf("%s\t",grupo[i][j]);
            printf("%s\t",salon[i][j]);
            printf("%s\t",profesor[i][j]);
            printf("%s\t",horario[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

estoy usando esta pagina para probar el codigo:

```
https://www.onlinegdb.com/ByDcHa-VS
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en los bucles internos, que son innecesarios. Con `nombre[i]` ya obtienes la referencia del array donde se deben guardar los datos con la función `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i, n;
    char nombre[9][9],grupo[9][9],salon[9][9],profesor[9][9],horario[9][9];
    printf("Cuantas materias quieres capturar\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Nombre de la materia no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",nombre[i]);
        printf("Grupo no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",grupo[i]);
        printf("Salon no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",salon[i]);
        printf("Profesor no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",profesor[i]);
        printf("Horario no.%d",i+1);
        scanf("%s",horario[i]);

    }

    printf("**********REPORTE DE MATERIAS CURSADAS  ACTUALMENTE************\n");
    printf("NOMBRE\tGRUPO\tSALON\tPROFESOR\tHORARIO\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\t",nombre[i]);
        printf("%s\t",grupo[i]);
        printf("%s\t",salon[i]);
        printf("%s\t",profesor[i]);
        printf("%s\t",horario[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: con respecto a este tipo de declaración: `scanf ("% s ", & nombre [i] [j]);` 1) siempre verifique el valor devuelto, no los valores de los parámetros, para asegurar que la operación fue exitosa. La familia de funciones `scanf` devuelve el número de especificadores de conversión de formato de entrada exitosos. 2) cuando use '%s' y / o '%[...]' siempre incluya un modificador MAX CHARACTERS que sea 1 menor que la longitud del búfer de entrada porque esos especificadores siempre agregan un carácter NUL.